# Run only on plug-in activation instead of wp_head

Tags: plugins, hooks, actions, user-roles, capabilities

I have below function on my plugin which adds more capabilities to current user.

```
// Role setting for add media
function wh_edit_roles(){
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){
        $user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
        $user->add_cap('edit_post');
        $user->add_cap('edit_others_pages');
        $user->add_cap('edit_published_pages');
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wh_edit_roles');
```

According to [WordPress's add_cap codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap), it is recommended to run this function on plugin activation.
What is the proper way to run this function on plugin activation instead of `wp_head` hook?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on whether your plugin is written in a procedural or object oriented style.

`register_activation_hook` is what you want.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

How exactly you incorporate it depends on your plugin coding style.  Examples listed in the Codex show multiple approaches.

Procedural example:
If you have a function called myplugin_activate() in the main plugin file at either:
wp-content/plugins/myplugin.php or
wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php

use this code:

```
function myplugin_activate() {

    // Activation code here...
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );
```

f your plugin uses the singleton class pattern, add the activation hook like so:

```
class MyPlugin {
     static function install() {
            // do not generate any output here
     }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'MyPlugin', 'install' ) );
```

Don't forget to include a companion deactivation hook, especially if you are setting cron jobs and performing other tasks that need clean-up if the plugin is deactivated or deleted.